# Set Images Multiple Clickable Zones in ListView Items?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, clickable-image

Click [[here]](http://wiresareobsolete.com/wordpress/2011/08/clickable-zones-in-listview-items/) This tutorial

Hi,
I am new to android,
I found this tutorial for Making list with multiple clickable zones. In a ListView that have multiple interactive locations that the user can touch, instead of just one single clickable row.

I require this kind of list in my project but I am unable to set different images on each row of list.

Please help Me  .

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ListView list = new ListView(this);
        setContentView(list);

        String[] items = {"Tom", "Sally", "Bill", "John", "Santiago", "Isabella"};
        //Supply this adapter with either R.layout.row_button, R.layout.row_view, or R.layout.row_view_noparent
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row_view, R.id.text, items) {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View row =  super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

                View left = row.findViewById(R.id.left);
                left.setTag(position);
                left.setOnClickListener(MyActivity.this);
                View right = row.findViewById(R.id.right);
                right.setTag(position);
                right.setOnClickListener(MyActivity.this);

                return row;
            }
        };

        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.left:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Left Accessory "+v.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.right:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Right Accessory "+v.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Item Click "+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

> ```
>  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
>     android:orientation="horizontal" >    
>     <ImageView
>         android:id="@+id/left"
>         android:layout_width="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
>         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>         android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
>         android:clickable="true"
>         android:scaleType="center"
>         android:src="@drawable/icon" />    
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/text"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_weight="1"
>         android:gravity="center"
>         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
>     <ImageView
>         android:id="@+id/right"
>         android:layout_width="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
>         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>         android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
>         android:clickable="true"
>         android:scaleType="center"
>         android:src="@drawable/icon" /></LinearLayout>
> ```

Comment: where from u are getting the images? from URLs or from the local.

Answer (score 1):

Use custom adapter and then fetch the id of imageview in getview method and apply onclicklistener.

Refer for [custom list](http://www.framentos.com/en/android-tutorial/2012/07/16/listview-in-android-using-custom-listadapter-and-viewcache/)